# Check permissions and reload the activity

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

Hi everyone I have a problem with load activity elements after checking runtime permission I made a app for Lollipop but now I need update to Marshmallow so I have this problem

I have a MainActivity

```
        public static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 1;

        @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                if(checkAndRequestPermissions(this)) {
                    //Var created
                    Internetstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusInternet);

                    if (!verificaConexion(this)) {
                        Internetstatus.setText("NOT CONNECTED");
                    } else {
                        Internetstatus.setText("CONNECTED");
                    }
                }
            }


            public static boolean verificaConexion(Context ctx) {

                boolean bConectado = false;
                ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (activeNetwork != null) {
                        bConectado = true;
                }
                return bConectado;
            }




        private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions(Context ctx) {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Checking permission…", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                //List of permissions
                int permissionInternet = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.INTERNET);

                int permissionAccessNetwork = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE);

                int permissionReadExternal = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                int permissionWriteExternal = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);


                List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

                //Verify status of permissions
                if (permissionInternet != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
                }
                if (permissionAccessNetwork != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE);
                }
                if (permissionReadExternal != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
                if (permissionWriteExternal != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }


                if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                    return false;
                }


                return true;

            }
            return true;
        }


    }
```

Right, I have more elements in the activity but with the only single text is fine for the example :), the checking permission is fine but when I press allow the permissions the activity text status is the default text xD! "Small Text", so the setText not work, but if I close the app and open again all work perfectly because I have allowed the permission yet. Hey is my first time that I make app for marshmallow, so maybe the problem is very stupid hahahha.

Well after that dont work I thought that maybe if I create a new activity LoadActivity I can check the permissions there (move function check and all about check permission from MainActivity to LoadActivity) and if the conditional is fine I initialize the MainActivity, this fine start new activity (LoadActivity), I check permissions but start the MainActivity dont work after I allow permissions

The new LoadActivity is

```
public class LoadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_load);

        if(checkAndRequestPermissions(this)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }


    }

    private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions(Context ctx) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Checking permission…", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
            //List of permissions
            int permissionInternet = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET);

            int permissionAccessNetwork = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE);

            int permissionReadExternal = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            int permissionWriteExternal = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);


            List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

            //Verify status of permissions
            if (permissionInternet != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
            }
            if (permissionAccessNetwork != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE);
            }
            if (permissionReadExternal != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
            if (permissionWriteExternal != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }


            if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                return false;
            }


            return true;

        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me :D
Regards

Comment: Where is your onRequestPermissionsResult?

Comment: When you allow the permission you get a call on ```onRequestPermissionsResult``` and in this method you get the permission status for all permission requested (status granted/denied). So in that method you have to update the activity.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!!!

Comment: Try this it will help u:-http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks so much guys now I can understand this, well i paste my new functional code, maybe can help to others.

```
public class LoadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_load);
        insertDummyContactWrapper();
    }

    final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 124;

    private void insertDummyContactWrapper() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();

            final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.INTERNET))
                permissionsNeeded.add("Internet.");
            if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE))
                permissionsNeeded.add("Internet Status.");
            if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
                permissionsNeeded.add("Read Files.");
            if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
                permissionsNeeded.add("Write Files.");

            if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
                if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
                    // Need Rationale
                    String message = "You need to grant access to " + permissionsNeeded.get(0);
                    for (int i = 1; i < permissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
                        message = message + ", " + permissionsNeeded.get(i);
                    showMessageOKCancel(message,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                        requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                                                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    return;
                }
                requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                        REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                return;
            }
        }
        startApp();

    }

    private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissionsList.add(permission);
                // Check for Rationale Option
                if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(LoadActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }




    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS:
            {
                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                // Initial
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.INTERNET, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                // Fill with results
                for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                    perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                // Check for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.INTERNET) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && perms.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // All Permissions Granted
                    startApp();
                } else {
                    // Permission Denied
                    Toast.makeText(LoadActivity.this, "Some Permission is Denied, please allow permission for that the app can work.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
            break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }


    private void startApp(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }


}
```

Hope it can help to others :D

For make it i based in articles commented by other users and finally from this article

https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

and recommend this video for noobs how me in android marshmallow

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8lUdPVSzDk

Regards!

Answer (score 3):

You check if the permission is granted then call setText else do nothing.

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(checkAndRequestPermissions(this)) { //Var created
        Internetstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusInternet);
        if (!verificaConexion(this)) {
            Internetstatus.setText("NOT CONNECTED");
        } else {
            Internetstatus.setText("CONNECTED"); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

If you want to setText after permission was granted then you should override method onRequestPermissionResult and call setText from this again. The activity onCreate method would not be called again after permission was granted.

Thats the point why it works when you close and reopen the app, because the new opening of your app calls activity onCreate again and now your method checkAndRequestPermissions returns true => setText will be called

Comment: Thanks! now I understand this :)

Answer (score 2):

Read this page: 
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

The major problem is you request permissions and then return false

```
if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
    return false;
}
```

So this if statement will not pass

```
if(checkAndRequestPermissions(this))
```

You must implement [onRequestPermissionsResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])) as has been said on comments.

Also, your method is private and not static so you don't need to pass `Context` as an argument, you can call `this` inside it like you do, just pointing not very important.

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo! now I can understand this :D

Answer (score 1):

By implementing the interface ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback we can check whether the user is given permission to the request. If given we can load the activity once again by implementing method called onRequestPermissionsResult. For more details check this link https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback  {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                if(isStoragePermissionGranted()) {
                    // code to implement after permission granted
                }
        }

    public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        String TAG = "logcheck";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
                Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {

                Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
    }     

        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){

                    boolean flag;
                    flag = true;
                    if(requestCode == 1)
                    {
                        for (int i:grantResults)
                        {
                            if( i == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
                                flag = false;

                        }
                        if (flag)
                        {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
                            finish();
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```